# Get Direct URL for uploads in search - Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-search

I have customized my search to look at images and documents as part of that search. This is working fine.  However I am not sure how to get the URL to the uploaded images/documents that are returned. Ideally there would be a link to download/display in browser.  I am ok with the ../media/images/xxx  url.  But I can't seem to figure out how to get that data in the template. Thoughts? Search is performed by this.

```
    # Search
if search_query:
    results = []
    page_results = Page.objects.live().search(search_query)
    if page_results:
        results.append({'page': page_results})
    doc_results = Document.objects.all().search(search_query)
    if doc_results:
        results.append({'docs': doc_results})
    img_results = Image.objects.all().search(search_query)
    if img_results:
        results.append({'image': img_results})
    search_results = list(chain(page_results, doc_results, img_results))
    query = Query.get(search_query)

    # Record hit
    query.add_hit()
else:
    search_results = Page.objects.none()
```

And the html looks like this

```
    {% if search_results %}

{{ count }} results found.
    {% for result in search_results %}
        {% for k, v in result.items %}
            {% if k == 'page' %}
                {% for item in v %}
                    <p>
                    <h4><a href="{% pageurl item %}">{{ item }}</a></h4>
                    Type: Article<br>
                    Author: {{ item.specific.owner.get_full_name }}<br>
                    Publish Date: {{ item.specific.last_published_at}} 
                    </p>
                {% endfor %}

            {% elif k == 'docs' %}
                {% for item in v %}
                    <p>
                    <h4><a href="">{{ item.title }}</a></h4>
                    Type: Document<br>
                    Publish Date: {{ item.created_at }}
                    </p>
                {% endfor %}
            {% elif k == 'image' %}
                {% for item in v %}
                    <p>
                    <h4><a href="">{{ item.title }}</a></h4>
                    Type: Image<br>
                    Publish Date: {{ item.created_at }}
                    </p>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif%}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}


    {% if search_results.has_previous %}
        <a href="{% url 'search' %}?query={{ search_query|urlencode }}&amp;page={{ search_results.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if search_results.has_next %}
        <a href="{% url 'search' %}?query={{ search_query|urlencode }}&amp;page={{ search_results.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
    {% endif %}
{% elif search_query %}
    No results found
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django provides the `url` property to files and images, and wagtail has this also.

```
{{ item.url }}
```

Wagtail has a great support for the redirect to files and integrates `django-sendfile` as well. Both of these methods allow for image downloading.

https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/images/image_serve_view.html

from wagtail.images.views.serve import ServeView

urlpatterns = [
...

```
re_path(r'^images/([^/]*)/(\d*)/([^/]*)/[^/]*$', ServeView.as_view(action='redirect'), name='wagtailimages_serve'),
```

]

** Edit below
Generating the image “as foo” to access individual properties - access the underlying image instance

```
{% image item original as item_img %}

{{ item_img.url }}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately item.url is an invalid tag.  So I suspect my view is not finding an URL for the image or document.  What I have been chasing for weeks. Not a fan of wagtail.

Comment: I updated the answer to include using the wagtail tag to give access to the image.  hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent.  That worked out.  I will note I had to add {% load wagtailimages_tags %} to my template page for the tags to pick up.   Do you know if there is an equivalent for documents? I was not able to find one in the documentation.

Comment: Maybe try using Document.objects.all().specific()?  if you are using a custom document model.

Comment: Not a custom model, just the vanilla upload for things like PDFs.  Document.object in this  case is from wagtail.documents.models.  But trying to do any sort of search for wagtail and documents just leads to headaches.  anyway you have resolved the issue for this thread.  Thank you.